# Creating several users in one request using Services/REST/Json

Tags: 7, services

I'm using [Services 7.x-3.12](https://www.drupal.org/node/2471847) and able to create a single new user using REST/Json post, and that works well.

Is it possible to create multiple new users in one request? I couldn't find any documentation on this and wasn't able to make it work. I tried separating the users with a comma inside the Json body, like so:

```
{{"username":"testuser27”,"mail”:"testuser27@gmail.com","pass”:"test","roles":"2","status":"1"},{"username":"testuser27”,"mail”:"testuser27@gmail.com","pass”:"test","roles":"2","status":"1”}}
```

but no success - I get this error:

```
[ "Missing required argument account" ]
```

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I read or heard somewhere that you can't do multiple stuff in one request.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box no.

But you could write a module that supplies you're own resource that takes multiple user objects.

Comment: Very cool idea! I can see how to create the custom resource, for example [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/783460), but how can I set the resource to take multiple user objects?